# How to search for string in Drupal database and replace

Tags: database

I am wondering what would be the safest way to search through the mysql database for a specific keyword and update.

More specifically here is what I am trying to do.

In many of the nodes we have videos embedded. Unfortunately, we didn't add preload="none" to our videos. Now the pages take a long time to fully load plus they download the whole video without the user clicking on it wasting bandwidth.

I want to search the nodes (mainly the body field) for:
video controls=""
and replace with 
video controls="controls" preload="none"

I assume I can use something like this? update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');

Which table should I search?

I don't want to mess up the database so a second opinion is highly appreciated.

Comment: The name of the table is whatever the field name is holding the data you are replacing, as well as its revision table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say which version of Drupal you are using.  If it's D7, there is the [scanner module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) which can probably do what you want.

If it is D8, I'd suggest writing a drush script to update the content.  The standardization of entities and methods makes that fairly easy. Here's a snippet of code from a script I used to grab all text from our site that needed to be translated.  You can modify it to do what you need.

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'article;
$fields = [
  'field_header' => 'paragraph',
  'field_summary' => 'text',
];

$entities = gen_i18n_get_entities($entity_type, $bundle);
foreach ( $entities as $vid => $id ) {
  $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($id);

  gen_i18n_parse_entity($entity, $fields, $page);
}

/**
 * Find the entity ids for the specified type and bundle.
 *
 * @param string $entity_type
 * @param string $bundle
 * @return array
 */
function gen_i18n_get_entities( $entity_type, $bundle ) {
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type)
    ->condition('type', $bundle);
  if ( $entity_type == 'node' ) {
    $query->condition('status', 1);
  }
  $results = $query->execute();
  return $results;
}
/**
 * Walk thru the entity fields to get required information.
 *
 * @param EntityInterface $entity
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $page
 */
function gen_i18n_parse_entity( EntityInterface $entity, array $fields, array &$page ) {
  global $field_num;

  $field_num = 0;
  foreach( $fields as $field => $field_type ) {
    if ( !in_array($field_type, array('alias', 'menu'))) {
      $field_def = $entity->getFieldDefinition($field);
      if ( $field_def != NULL ) {
        $label = $field_def->getLabel();
      }
      else {
        print "** Could not find field {$field} in {$entity->bundle()} {$entity->id()}\n";
        continue;
      }
    }
    else {
      $label = $field_type;
    }
    switch ( $field_type ) {
      case 'text':
        gen_i18n_parse_text( $entity, $field, $page, $label);
        break;
      case 'paragraph':
        gen_i18n_parse_paragraph($entity, $field, $page, $label);
        break;
      case 'metatags':
        gen_i18n_parse_metatags( $entity, $field, $page, $label);
        break;
      case 'alias':
        $field_num++;
        $page['en']["{$field_num} - URL"] =  $entity->toURL()->toString();
        break;
      case 'menu':
        gen_i18n_parse_menu($entity, $field, $page);
        break;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In D8, albeit a riskier method, but one when you don't know the names of the tables you are looking for would be to use a MySQL stored procedure: http://kevinquillen.com/drupal/2017/07/13/mass-updating-drupal-fields-with-mysql-stored-procedure-pt-2 -- it definitely has drawbacks, but I have used it successfully to update mass tables and field values instantly.

Comment: New link: https://kevinquillen.com/mass-updating-drupal-fields-mysql-stored-procedure-pt-2